Editing the f-curve of the object 'freezes' it's animation
File in question
I'm making a viewmodel animation, but everytime i try to edit the f-curve of the rifle, the animation doesn't play anymore, it freezes on the current frame and scrolling through the timeline doesn't do anything. Specifically, if i edit a keyframe in the graph editor or even just select one. The only way to fix it is to Ctrl+z undo. None of the models or rigs are mine.

Please upload more information about your project and the issue. At best, you can use blend-exchange.com to upload your file (with just the relevant parts) so others can help you.

Hi, 505.. with the information here, I'm afraid we can only guess.Please edit to provide more.. you can include an image of the f-curve, and indicate the difference between what you want, and what you've got.. (the animation you are looking for.) .. and anything else that might help us help you. At the moment, the question is not answerable.. edit, and we'll re-open for you.

Hi, again, 505, nearly there.. your file requires permission to upload. Can you share your file, or  a representative file on https://blend-exchange.com/ if it's too large or you want to protect your content?

I fixed it by applying all transforms on my armature.
